# About $F_{xy}(x, y) = F_{yx}(x, y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose that $f(t)$, $g(t)$ have a 2nd order derivative.

Let $F(x, y) := x f(\frac{y}{x}) + g(\frac{y}{x})$.

Then, $F_{xy}(x, y) = F_{yx}(x, y)$.

$F$ is not a class $C^2$ function in general.

Is there a necessary and sufficient condition to be $F_{xy}(x, y) = F_{yx}(x, y)$ when $F(x, y)$ has all the 2nd order partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, its called Schwarz theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives 
It states that any $C^2$ function has this property.

Comment: Is the following statement true? If $F$ satisfies $F_{xy} = F_{yx}$, then $F$ is a class $C^2$ function.

Comment: I think the theorem says that if $F$ is a class $C^2$ function, then $F_{xy} = F_{yx}$.